# How to "open" on a "filtered" port

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, nmap

I am running:

```
$ ssh user@ip_address
```

and waiting for long time without response.
I try to verify the status of my port:

```
$ a=`nmap ip_address -PN -p ssh | grep filtered`
$ echo $a      
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

so to confirm that there is a filter?  How can I get rid of this filter?

I checked then:

```
$ netstat -tln 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address                   State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

and:

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'ssh[d]'
root      1017     1  0 10:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

The Ubuntu installation is "virgin" so I doubt that there is some problem related to firewall on my system. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any idea about how to proceed how to and open the port safely? I really need to enable this computer for ssh connection from outside.

Comment: Please include output of `netstat -tln` and `ps -ef | grep 'ssh[d]'` on the server.

Comment: @bonsaiviking I included the output you required. I just modified some number because I am not sure it is safe to post exactely what I got on a server. How do you suggest to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Open the port in your firewall (assuming for a moment this is where it is filtered). On the server (computer you wish to `ssh` to), try this:

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

in a shell, then post any error message here.

Also, please post the output of

```
sudo netstat -tlpn
```

especially if the firewall command does not work, so that we can see the LISTEN port of `sshd`.

If the `netstat` command above cannot be found (new iproute2 tools) then try instead

```
sudo ss -tlpn
```

The output is less readable than that of `netstat` but should still show the `sshd` process doing a "LISTEN" on Port 22.

Answer (score 0):

Something between you and ip_address is blocking the connection to ip_address:22 such that no response is received. That could be the ip_address server itself or any box between you and it.

You will need to track down where the block is occurring and open the port.

Comment: Thanks lain, but it is quite obvious that I need to track where the block is occurring, but since I am not an expert, I don't know how to do that. Do you have some specific suggestion?

Comment: @dario - it's your network, therefore you should know it's configuration.  As Iain says, something is blocking the packet getting through so `nmap` shows it as `filtered`.  Confirm that there is no firewall on your Ubuntu server and then confirm that there are no firewalls in between you and the server which are blocking port 22.

Comment: @ garethTheRed - thanks. Can you tell me how to do that? I really have no idea. I tried to execute ssh from my computer into the same computer with the same result. Can this help? I read that Ubuntu was released with no default firewall, that is why I would exclude this option. Otherwise I have no clue about how to go further.....